# Symfony2 querying a specific value form the database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

A simple shop. A user has money in his balance account and when he buys something the balance needs to be decreased based on the sum of the cart. I have an action that is redirected if the payment was successful. If it was I want to decrease the balance like this:

```
  /**
     * @Route("/successfull", name="successfull_purchase")
     * @Template("MediaparkLtUserBundle:User:paymentConfirmed.html.twig")
     */
    public function successfullPurchaseAction(Request $request) {
        $currentUser = $this->getCurrentUser(); // logged users id
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('MediaparkLtUserBundle:User')->find($currentUser);
        $pay = $em->getRepository('MediaparkLtUserBundle:AccountMovement')->findOneBy(array('user'=>$currentUser));
        $sum = $pay->getAmount();
        $balance = $user->getNonpayableFunds();
        $newBalance = $balance - $sum;

        $user->setNonpayableFunds($newBalance);

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        return array('user' => $user, 'pay'=> $pay);
    }
```

As you can see im querying two tables. In User table im getting the current user. In AccountMovement I am getting the movement based on that user.

So I am trying to get the Amount on the specific time, but I always get the first buy.

For example:

AccountMovement table:

```
id-1
user_id - 5
amount - 50.00

id-2
user_id - 5
amount - 5.00
```

With my query I always get the first input, whitch is 50.00. I need to get the last(or current input). How can I do that? Is it possible to do something like this:

```
$pay = $em->getRepository('MediaparkLtUserBundle:AccountMovement')->findOneBy(array('user'=>$currentUser, 'DESC')); (to get the last input)??
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could the the similar thing:

```
$pay = $em->getRepository('MediaparkLtUserBundle:AccountMovement')
        ->findBy(array('user'=>$currentUser), array('id' => 'DESC'), 1)[0];
```

Not ideal, but it should work. Be aware that this could throw `OutOfRangeException` if no results exist in the database.

Why not store the last amount of money in `User` itself? Or some other entity which is related to `User` entity?

Also, be sure to wrap that action in DB transaction via `beginTransaction()` and `commit()`.